# How to bulk transfer ownership of Google docs inside a Google drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, access-control

I created a Google drive folder to which I gave an access to multiple people.

These people have created sub folders inside this and have created multiple Google docs inside these. They are now the owners of these Google docs.

I want to remove them from being owner of these Google docs. One way is to manually ask them but it's very difficult as there are hundreds of documents.

How can I remove them from being owner of these doc's that they have created inside my Google drive?

Comment: Do you have G Suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using G Suite, which is a paid, business form of Google Drive. In G Suite Business and G Suite Enterprise, you can create a [**Shared Drive**](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7212025?hl=en), in which all the files that contributors make are owned by your organisation. [See this answer as well.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125451/109353)

In My Drive, you cannot ask the owners of hundreds of files to transfer their ownership. That is impractical. You can, however, simply copy those files. The copies will be owned by you.

Answer (score 0):

I used the tool below to bulk transfer a set of files and folders to another account. It worked for me!

https://gsuitetips.com/tools/change-owner/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: https://www.cloudwards.net/transfer-ownership-google-drive/

There are exceptions to this. If you’re the administrator of your company’s Workspace account, you can change the owner of any file or folder stored on that account, as long as it was created by someone on the same account.

Likewise, if your business uses a Workspace account, and your contractor or employee is on that same account, then they can transfer ownership of their files to other people within the company themselves.